# Jmeter fails to connect to MongoDB and throws error

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to connect to Mongo DB with following code:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import java.util.Arrays;


try {

String mongoUser = vars.get("mongouser");
String userDB = vars.get("userdb");
char[] password = vars.get("password").toCharArray();
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoUser, userDB, password);
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
.applyToClusterSettings {builder -> 
builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(vars.get("mongoHost"),vars.get("mongoPort").toInteger())))}
.build();
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);

MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(vars.get("databaseName"));
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(vars.get("collectionName"));
vars.putObject("collection", collection);
return "Connected to " + vars.get("collectionName");
}
catch (Exception e) {
SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

But its failing with error:

```
Response code: 500
Response message: Exception: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method com.mongodb.ServerAddress#<init>.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null, class java.lang.Integer] due to overlapping prototypes between:
[class java.lang.String, int]
[class java.net.InetAddress, int]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [InetAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)

```
builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(InetAddress.getByName(vars.get("mongoHost")),vars.get("mongoPort").toInteger())))}
.build();
```